# How to center a div but left align text inside?

Tags: html, css

I want to put a div block in the center of a page, but the text should stay left of the centered block.

The problem is when I set the `div` to center and `p` to left, the content inside `p` is on the left of entire page not the left of centered block.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.container p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: God knows what you are saying here. No offense.

Comment: add a max-width

Comment: I add lots of details for both why and how, check it out below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the text is always left. And you should give width to the container or it will be of full size as of the page.

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="another-container">
    <p>Some text goes here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why the height ? and better use max-width

Comment: I just added height so that it can look like a box and border to show the position of the box. Its for understanding purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `margin: auto;` or `margin: 0 auto;` is the correct approach, however `div` is block level element, and it occupies the entire available width by default, so the `margin: auto;` has no effects visually.

All you need is to declare the `width` or `max-width` that is either percentage or fixed, as long as it's smaller than the parent element.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
```

Additionally, You can do it with `display: table;` because it has the ***shrink-to-fit*** feature. This works even without any width being set there.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="max-width: 500px;">
  <h2>Example: max-width and wrapping text</h2>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
</div>
```

Or, `display: inline-block;` similar feature as above. Note, an additional wrapper is required if you don't want to target the `body` tag.

```css
.outer {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean at the center of the page ? Else you can do like this

```
div.container {
   text-align: center;
   max-width : 700px;
   margin : auto;
   background : blue;
   }

p {
    text-align: left;
}
```